# Can't apply adjustments to a smart object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, smartobject

Can't apply adjustments to a smart object

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an adjustment layer. It works, Put the "Next layer only" switch ON, if you want to limit the effect to one layer. Actually you could open the smart object for edits, but that destroys the idea of fully undoable (=non-destructive) editing. Find it by right clicking the layer in the layers panel.